# How do I install the blazorhybrid project template?

Tags: blazor, maui

I'm trying to test the new dotnet 6 feature with hosting blazor in desktop applications, according to [this article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/blazor-on-desktop).

So im trying to use the command

```
dotnet new blazorhybrid -o BlazorHybrid
```

which does not work since i do not have the template it seems.

When searching for it with

```
dotnet new blazorhybrid --search
```

I can find the template which I am looking for. The command gives the instuction to install the template with

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.MobileBlazorBindings.Templates
```

which seems to do nothing but listing my current available templates. So, how do I install this template? Am I missing some kind of prerequisite? I have net6 preview 1 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest project templates for Mobile Blazor Bindings, including the hybrid template, is `dotnet new -i Microsoft.MobileBlazorBindings.Templates::0.5.50-preview`.
See the [Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/get-started) documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks, adding the version part solved it.